# Azure B2C: where can I find the AzureBlue default templates and selfAsserted.cshtml?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure B2C Custom Policies, following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy&tabs=applications#custom-policy-starter-pack

In the Custom policy starter pack, in the file `LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml`, there is this code:

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
  <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.7</DataUri>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account sign up page</Item>
  </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>
```

How do I find the source code for `~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All templates are available on GitHub: [Azure AD B2C HTML tempaltes](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/html-templates)

Alternatively, replace `~` with  `https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/static`.
So for self-asserted it would be `https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/static/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfasserted.cshtml`